# I'm trying to change the style of the <% and %> denotation in Visual Studio, where are the referred to in the settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Currently the ***<%*** tags in my VS editor show a bright yellow and I wanted to change the setting under tools->options.

What are they called under settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools->Options->Environment->Font Colors->HTML Server Side Script